# Multiple collations for the same MariaDB column?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, collation, culture

How to perform ORDER BY for string columns efficiently, when different collations are required, depending on the culture? That is, data for the users from different cultures are stored in the same table and the same column, but each user naturally wants to see it ordered according to it's locale (locale is of course known and fixed per each row in the table). And table can be very long, so column needs and index and can't be post-processed on the application side to the desired collation (it's database task to do heavy-lifting, right?).

For example, the `utf8_general_ci` produces different results from `utf8_swedish_ci`.

While I think the problem should be evident for any international project, I can't find any suitable solutions out there. Myself I can imaging only the following solutions, which are not that nice and I doubt nothing better can be done:

1. Use a separate field for each collation
2. Maybe, a view can be created per culture and indexed accordingly (I have not worked with MariaDB views though, so this is quite theoretical)
3. Use a separate "surrogate" field just for collation, maybe VIRTUAL

Now, if there were only one sortable string column, but there may be several. What is the intended and right way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you use the same character set (utf8 in your case) for column storage as well as for reading, you can use `COLLATE some-utf8-collation` after the `ORDER BY column-name` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable ORDER BY somecolumn COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci
```

In my tests this produces different sorting than a german collation:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable ORDER BY somecolumn COLLATE utf8_german2_ci
```

Well, as long as the data contains relevant characters, e.g. german umlauts üöä. If not, you won't see a difference.

Multiple columns in the `ORDER` clause each get their own `COLLATE` term:

```
SELECT * FROM sometable
ORDER BY
    somecolumn COLLATE utf8_german2_ci,
    secondcolumn COLLATE utf8_german2_ci
```

Comment: This is fine for "small" tables.  Tacking on the `COLLATE` clause prevents use of any `INDEX`, since the index is already in a specific collation.

Comment: Oh yes, that's correct. `EXPLAIN` says "using index, using filesort" when using a different collation in the `COLLATE` clause. Well, in that case one should find a way to duplicate relevant columns in the wanted collation, while minimizing effort with that when populating. A virtual column does not help here, as they cannot get an `INDEX`, a persistent column can, but `EXPLAIN` says that it always uses filesorting in a `SELECT`. So you will end up in manually populating additional columns with the wanted collation. Hm, quite worse.

Comment: Filesort happens for many reasons; let's see the specific query and `CREATE TABLE` to discuss it.

Comment: Can't get rid of filesort even for simplest string column with an index (no matter what collation used or omitted). While this answer is good enough for now (thanks!), I hope for an answer covering use of indexes for sort. But I am also using limit, so maybe this is of relevance: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/filesort-with-small-limit-optimization/